# Type issue in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ienumerable

I am getting an error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyProject.Models.MyRecord]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MyProject.Models.MyRecord'

When running my MVC app. Here is my view:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyProject.Models.MyRecord>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Details</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

        <% foreach (MyProject.Models.MyRecord r in Model){%>
           <%=r.Property1 %>
        <%} %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My controller action is as follows:

```
 public ActionResult DisplayRecords(string id)
{
    MyRecordContext rc = new MyRecordContext();


    List<MyRecord> rl = rc.MyRecords.Where(x => x.RecordID == id).ToList();

    return View(rl);
}
```

MyRecord class is decalred as:  public class MyRecord : IEnumerable

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: You are returning a `List<MyRecord>` from your action but declare `MyRecord` as your view page model.

Comment: Change the first line of you view to be `<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<System.Collections.Generic.List<MyProject.Models.MyRecord>>" %>` and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks DavidG, worked like a charm. Could you please post an answer so I could accept it?